# Which recommendation algorithm should be used?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, knn, recommendation-engine

Favorite data of multiple users (no more than 10000) are as follows:

```
user1:  url_ 1, url_ 5, url_ 13, url_ 104, ....
user2:  url_ 3, url_ 20, url_ 104, url_ 638, ....
user3:  url_ 11, url_ 13, url_ 57, url_ 104, ....
....
userN: url_ 3, url_ 310, url_ 517, url_ 638, ....
```

The number of favorite url for each user is generally tens to hundreds, and at most not more than 1000, but the possibility of url is unlimited.

All user are filtered by conditions in advance. So the repeatability of each user's favorite url is estimated to be between 3% and 20%.

What algorithm is most suitable for calculating the similarity between users? Thanks.

Comment: The number of users is less than 10000 and the number of urls per user is between 10 and 1000. Good. "The possibility of url is unlimited". Okay. That does raise one question: How much intersection/verlap between users do you expect? Theoretically, user1 could have 100 urls, which are all urls shared by other users; or user1 could have 100 urls, but only 1 of those urls is shared by another user. Do you have any information as the amount of overlap between users?

Comment: If it is completely random, of course, there will be very little overlap between these urls. However, in this case, the users to be analyzed are filtered by conditions in advance, so there will certainly be some overlap between their favorite urls. I initially expect it to be about 3% - 20%.

Comment: This is relevant information, I suggest using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74598248/edit) button to include it in the question post.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the similarity between two unordered subsets (no duplicates) from the same universe. The most common distance measure for this use case is the [Jaccard similarity coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).